# Remover uma foreign key de um servidor em produção?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela `cad_address` com o registro do endereço dos meus usuários. Tenho também uma outra tabela de pedidos `mov_order` que tem uma foreign key `address_id` para a tabela de endereços, responsável pelo relacionamento.

O problema é que quando o cara atualiza o endereço, atualiza também o endereço do pedido (por conta do relacionamento). Por causa disso, estamos criando um “snapshot” do endereço na tabela de pedidos, com todos os dados do endereço, agora também no pedido (uma réplica).

Agora no status do pedido não buscaremos mais o endereço do cliente pelo relacionamento, e sim, diretamente na tabela de pedido, tendo então o endereço que estava cadastrado no momento da compra. Aproveitamos a foreign key `address_id`, para fazer a migração dos dados do endereço do cliente, para a tabela de pedido.

Porém, sentimos agora, que a tabela de pedido ficou meio suja. O fato é que, temos uma coluna `address_id`, setando um relacionamento que não está sendo usado para nada. E esse relacionamento pode confundir os desenvolvedores, sem contar, que pode abrir uma brecha pra que alguém faça uma pequena 'cagada', chamar um relacionamento que não está mais sendo utilizado...

A pergunta é: É correto remover essa coluna? Ou deve-se mantê-la?

Comment: Se já tem uma réplica dos dados, remova a coluna `address_id`, como você mesmo disse, ela não agrega nada além de poder causar confusão com os programadores. Além disso, você já tem a tabela de pedidos relacionada a tabela de clientes que por sua vez está relacionada aos endereços. Obs: É importante avisar aos clientes que o endereço da entrega não poderá ser alterado após a compra.

Comment: Opa! Primeiramente, obrigado pela resposta cara, realmente ajudou muito! Mas tem um problema que eu esqueci de citar ali em cima, eu tenho tudo isso já pronto para rodar nas 'migrations' do laravel. Ela vai adicionar os novos campos e migrar os dados para esses novos campos. Já testei e dá certo, tudo perfeitamente. O problema é que eu tenho que desenvolver tbm o rollback dela, que seria a alternativa caso dê algo errado, e o problema desse caso é que se eu remover essa coluna ao rodar a migration, se eu precisar por acaso rodar o rollback, eu não vou mais ter os valores da foreign key setados

Comment: Como o rollback do Laravel só cuida da estrutura e não dos dados, você teria que fazer o backup da tabela, e caso precise de um rollback, teria que restaurar ela com outro nome (exemplo: mov_order_old), e depois recriar a coluna address_id na tabela mov_order e em seguida atualizar os valores a partir dos existentes em mov_order_old.

Comment: Mas quando/como eu removeria essa tabela de backup? Eu fiquei pensando aqui, realmente faz sentido, criar uma tabela de backup para rodar a migration e no rollback atualizar a tabela de pedidos utilizando a tabela de backup... Porém, eu teria que versionar essa tabela tbm? Por que e se no caso, acontece alguma coisa alguns dias depois do deploy e eu precise fazer o rollback...

Comment: Sim, para ficar completo e com possibilidade de rollback, teria que versionar a tabela sim.

Comment: O problema afinal de contas é com Laravel? Se não for,  vou tirar as tags, para ficar mais fácil de relacionar os assuntos. Parece-me ser mais uma questão simplesmente de banco de dados, acho que nem o PHP deveria estar como tag.

Comment: O laravel tem relação pelo fato de eu estar utilizando o sistema de migrations do laravel para fazer as migrações, e os recursos deles são um tanto limitados. Por isso ataquei as tags

Comment: O sistema usa migrations, mas a pergunta não fala nada sobre a migration do Laravel. Você usa as tags apenas para destacar o assunto da pergunta, e não o que você usa em desenvolvimento. Eu também confundia esse ponto.

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado pela orientação, e desculpa por qualquer coisa.

Comment: Está tudo bem, eu também confundia isso.